# SQL Server Median Function

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_Get_Average_Order_Size_Median]
(
      @ITEM char(15)
)
RETURNS decimal(21,6)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT @Median = AVG(1.0 * QTYSHP)
FROM
(
    SELECT o.QTYSHP, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.QTYSHP), c.c 
    FROM dbo.tbl AS o 
        WHERE RQDATE >=DATEADD (mm,-6, GETDATE()) 
        AND PRICE != '0' 
        AND SALESMN != 'WB' 
        AND item = @ITEM )  

   +
    SELECT o.QTYSHP, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.QTYSHP), c.c
    FROM tbl 
        WHERE RQDATE >=DATEADD (mm,-6, GETDATE()) 
        AND PRICE != '0' 
        AND SALESMN != 'WB' 
        AND item = @ITEM  
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT c = COUNT(*) 
               FROM dbo.tblS) AS c
                   WHERE RQDATE >=DATEADD (mm,-6, GETDATE()) 
                   AND PRICE != '0' 
                   AND SALESMN != 'WB' 
                   AND item = @ITEM
   +  
   (SELECT c = COUNT(*) 
    FROM dbo.tblS) AS c
        WHERE RQDATE >=DATEADD (mm,-6, GETDATE()) 
        AND PRICE != '0' 
        AND SALESMN != 'WB' 
        AND item = @ITEM
   ) AS x
WHERE rn IN ((c + 1)/2, (c + 2)/2);


      @Return = @Median
      BEGIN 

      END
      RETURN @Return

END TRANSACTION...
```

Is this the correct median function? Please correct me ..I'm learning

Comment: Title says SQL server tag is mysql

Comment: Pass some values and test if it is returning the data you need.

Answer (score 2):

The **median** is the value that accumulates 50% of the values (the 50% percentile). So I think the simplest way to do it is:

1. Count the number of records (let's say this count is 'n')
2. Select the top `n / 2` records (if `n` is even, round it to the next integer value), sorted by the column that holds the value for which you want to calculate the median. Read the biggest (last) value of this column.

I'm not quite familiar with SQL server, but in MySQL I would do it like this:

```
set @n = (select count(*) from yourTable);
set @med = ceil(@n / 2);
select yourColumn
from (
    select yourColumn
    from yourTable
    order by yourColumn
    limit @med
) as a
order by yourColumn desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2005+ you could try this solution:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Value NUMERIC(9,2)
);
INSERT  @MyTable (ID, Value) VALUES (1, 10);
INSERT  @MyTable (ID, Value) VALUES (2, 20);
INSERT  @MyTable (ID, Value) VALUES (3, 30);
INSERT  @MyTable (ID, Value) VALUES (4, 40);

-- Test #1: 4 rows => AVG(20,30)
SELECT  AVG(y.Value) AS Median#1
FROM
(
SELECT  *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.ID ASC) AS RowNumASC,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.ID DESC) AS RowNumDESC
FROM    @MyTable x
) y
WHERE y.RowNumASC = y.RowNumDESC
OR y.RowNumASC + 1 = y.RowNumDESC
OR y.RowNumASC - 1 = y.RowNumDESC;
-- End of Test #1

-- Test #2: 5 rows => AVG(30)
INSERT  @MyTable (ID, Value) VALUES (5, 50);
SELECT  AVG(y.Value) AS Median#2
FROM
(
SELECT  *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.ID ASC) AS RowNumASC,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.ID DESC) AS RowNumDESC
FROM    @MyTable x
) y
WHERE y.RowNumASC = y.RowNumDESC
OR y.RowNumASC + 1 = y.RowNumDESC
OR y.RowNumASC - 1 = y.RowNumDESC;
-- End of Test #2
```

Results:

```
Median#1
---------
25.000000

Median#2
---------
30.000000
```

Comment: Thank you But I can't understand that how to get ave value using two tables?

Comment: @user2755462: One simple solution is to replace `FROM @MyTable` data source with a derived table thus:`FROM (SELECT ... FROM a JOIN B ...) x`.